# Infinite Scroll Distance - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, infinite-scroll, electron, nginfinitescroll

I am using Angular2 for my application. I understand that the syntax to use infinite scroll is:

```
<div (scroll) = "scrollHandler()">
</div>
```

But is there any way we can specify anything like "infinite-scroll-distance", in Angular2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38252057/5868331

Answer (score 1):

You can use (window:scroll)="moving($event)" in html

```
<div (window:scroll)= "scrollHandler()"></div>
```

Try to use it on outer div