# Angular material virtual scroll with remote data

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 7 application I want to add the [material virtual scroll](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) to a mat-list, the data I have to show is load remotely with pagination, so for example I want to show 5 item per page, and when I scroll down some event need to be fired so I can load other 5 elements.

I don't understand if the material's virtual scroll can do this, all the example don't load data remotely.

this is the list:

```
<mat-list>
   <mat-list-item *ngFor="let prod of prodToOrder">
       <div>{{ prod.productName }}</div>
   </mat-list-item> 
 </mat-list>
```

In the past I used ngx-infinitescroll but now I want to use material if possible.

Comment: try this if works [scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038429/3584881)

Comment: but is not a material way