# How to get clientHeight in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried to get client height when I scroll page:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event) {
   if ($event.scrollHeight - $event.scrollTop === $event.clientHeight) {
    console.log('scrolled to the end');
  }
});
```

I need to detect if user scrolled to the end of page

Comment: `document.documentElement.clientHeight` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it like this ([see this post for other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664766/how-to-detect-scroll-to-bottom-of-html-element/42547136), [and this article for this solution](https://brianflove.com/2016/10/10/angular-2-window-scroll-event-using-hostlistener/)):

```
@HostListener("window:scroll") onWindowScroll() {
    let scroll = window.pageYOffset ||
                 document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
                 document.body.scrollTop || 0;

    const max = document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
                document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    if (scroll === max) {
        alert('Bottom');
    }
}
```

> See the [Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-to-bottom-notif)

Answer (score 1):

To get the height:

```
 var height = $window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: I dot use JQUERY

Comment: This isn't using jQuery. $window is a part of angular. So you should compare your scroll height to the window height.

Comment: Okay, then how to replace this code: `if ($event.scrollHeight - $event.scrollTop === $event.clientHeight) {
    console.log('scrolled to the end');
  }`?

Comment: I need to detect if user scrolled to the end of page

Comment: if ($window.scrollY  + $window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight) { // end of page }