# active function when scroll go to end page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to execute a function when the scrollbar reaches the bottom of the page.

How do I know if the scroll has reached the end of the page?

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onScroll(): void {
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        console.log('end')
    }
}
```

but it not work .

**How can i do this work ????**

Comment: check this fiddle for a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/W75mP/. You can easily implement this in angular.

Comment: @Saqib how can i use this angular ???

Comment: you cannot add hostlistener like so, hostlistener is to listen to events on the host. and unless you can add this directive to "window" you cannot listen to its scroll!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect scroll to bottom of html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664766/how-to-detect-scroll-to-bottom-of-html-element)

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547136/9386929

Comment: @mr-dortaj see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using that example is pretty easy. You can use the code inside the component's `.ts` file to use it. Check out this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-yw1bk) on CodeSandBox. I have implemented the fiddle in angular.

[Here](https://yw1bk.csb.app/) you can see the full-screen preview of the demo.

Comment: it have problem . i can not using the angular function

Comment: Have you checked the full-screen preview of the demo? Also, can you explain which issue are you facing?