# How to integrate Primeng datatable with ngx-infinite-scroll

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll, primeng-datatable, nginfinitescroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am trying to integrate ngx-infinite scroll library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll

with a primeng grid

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4.3.0/#/datatable

Has anyone tried to integrate those together or any other datatable.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No we ended up going different route

Comment: may I know what route you followed? I am stuck with infinite scrolling using primeng table and cannot find any solution to get it working. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirement is.. i added scroll event listener, while at it reaches end datatable body, i make a api call to load next set of records

Comment: That exactly what I am looking for. Can you please show me how you have captured scroll event? I will be really thankful.

Comment: @AdnanSheikh, i used browser events using DOM API. There are many ways of doing it. This is one example which shows how it can be done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664766/how-to-detect-scroll-to-bottom-of-html-element

Comment: I have been trying to catch element scroll using Angular HostListner, window scroll works fine but when I try to catch element scroll it doesn't seem to work. I guess we also have to put (scroll)="onElementScroll($event)" on the specific div tag in html to get it working. But as we are working with Primeng Table I couldn't understand where we should put it. I am almost there but missing something. Can you please help? I will be grateful.