# Enable the button when the user has reached end of the page by scrolling

Tags: html, css, angular8

I am trying to create a terms and conditions page where I have 'I Agree' button which should be disabled when the user is at the top/middle of the page. When the user reaches the end of the page the button should be enabled. For that I want to have Hostlistner/Directive/event binding which will listen to scroll and get the position of the scroll and inform when it reaches at bottom and enable I agree button. Is there any other way of doing it? I am new to angular. Thanks in advance

my html

```
<div class="modal-body" #agreement>
           <h6 class="inittext">You must scroll to the end of the terms and conditions And press "Agree" 
            to continue with your request.</h6> 
            <p style="font-weight:bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br></p>
            <p> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
              ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. 
              Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis
               cras. Sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque.<br></p>
               <p style="font-weight:bold"> Fermentum posuere urna <br></p>
                <p>nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat. Ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat 
               interdum varius. Habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Dictum non 
               consectetur a erat nam. Duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo. 
               Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum. Massa sapien faucibus 
               et molestie ac.</p>
               <p style="font-weight:bold">Mi bibendum <br></p>
               <p> neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus 
                 accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Sit amet
                  venenatis urna cursus eget.<br></p> 
                  <p>Eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Enim praesent 
                  elementum facilisis leo vel. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum. Arcu 
                  cursus vitae congue mauris. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. Rhoncus 
                  est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis.<br></p> <p> Tristique senectus et
                   netus et malesuada. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. 
                   Sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec 
                   dui nunc. Purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.</p>
                   <h6 class="inittext">You must press "Agree" to continue with your request.</h6>
         </div> 
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="float: left">Save as PDF</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Disagree</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Agree</button>
        </div>
```

My ts file

```
import { Component,ElementRef, ViewChild, HostListener, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('agreement') agreement : ElementRef;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *scrollTop* and *height* information in connection with the current position.

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.documentElement.offsetHeight
document.documentElement.scrollHeight
```

For more details, have a closer look at this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547136/9293934

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I implemented this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038429/10977529